# How can an Hibernate web application start if its database is not yet available

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sessionfactory

What would be the best way to setup/design or simply configure an Hibernate based Java web application to support being started (i.e. sessionfactory initialization) up if the database connectivity is not yet available, but will be, albeit at a much later time.

In other words, is there an easy way to handle out of order initialization between an Hibernate server application and its database?

Comment: I would use jdbc to test the connection. Until the database connectivity is not available, not start to sessionfactory initialization.

Comment: We're pulling the database connection through JNDI - afaics even if the database is down, the application starts. However, accessing the database will kick off a runtime exception, though it will recover once the database is back on.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know . If you use external connection pool and hibernate is no responsible to making the connections and in additional hbm2ddl is set to none than hibernate should not connect to the database untill you open a session. 
Any way if it will failed to open session because there is no connection it will success to open new session as soon as there is databas connectivity.